# Necesito pasar el contenido de un EditText de un activity a otro en Android

Tags: android

necesito si pueden ayudarme a que el contenido de un edit text que lo pase a una variable este disponible para un activity cuando el sea ejecutado por el usuario, es decir me parece que sea una variable global o es otro concepto, muchas gracias. Esto es en

Comment: Puedes almacenar el texto del `EditText` en `SharedPreferences` y luego acceder a el desde la otra actividad. Para poder ayudarte mejor, agrega el código que tienes hasta ahora.

Answer (score 1):

Bienvenido a Stackoverflow lo que necesitas es:
Primeramente extraer el texto del EditText,Para el caso genérico de pasar un simple String lo deberemos añadir en el Intent de lanzamiento de la nueva Activity;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_Origen.this, Activity_Destino.class);
intent.putExtra("parametro", "string");
startActivity(intent);
```

Recuperando luego desde el otro Activity ese String de esta manera:

```
getIntent().getExtras().getString("parametro");
```

y listo.

Comment: Eso lo hice y funciona pero no deseo pasarlo a esa activity en ese momento sino cuando se abra la actividad por el usuario.

Answer (score 0):

Hace poco tuve que hacer lo mismo pero con bastantes variables, lo que hice fue crear una clase que llame "App" (puedes llamarla como quieras), y ahi puedes añadir, en tu caso, lo siguiente:

```
public class App {

public static String contenidoEditText="";
```

}

Ahora, desde la primera activity, obtienes el contenido del EditText y lo guardas en la variable creada anteriormente:

```
 String datoEditText = nombreEditText.getText().toString();
//Guardamos el dato en la variable de la clase App
 App.contenidoEditText=datoEditText ;
```

Y por último, desde la ultima activity, que es la que abres, obtienes el contenido que has guardado en la clase App:

```
String obtenerContenido = App.contenidoEditText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer lo que pides, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

Obtiene el valor en `String` del contenido del EditText

```
EditText edit = findViewById(eidt);
String texto = edit.getText().toString();
```

Con este valor ya capturado puedes guardarlo con `SharedPreferences`

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("string",texto);
editor.commit();
```

Una vez guardado este `String`, puedes acceder a el desde cualquier actividad o fragmento

**Desde una actividad:**

```
SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String valorGuardado = shared.getString("string", ""); //Las comillas vacías son el valor por defecto por si no se ha guardado ningún valor en esta variable de preferencia
```

**Desde un fragmento:**

```
SharedPreferences shared = getActivity.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String valorGuardado = shared.getString("string", ""); //Las comillas vacías son el valor por defecto por si no se ha guardado ningún valor en esta variable de preferencia
```